# How does the ICL7660 work?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have used the ICL7660 successfully to generate a -9V negative rail from a +9V battery.

I wonder how this works.

Between -9V output and +9V input there is suddenly an 18V difference.

Is the chip stepping up the voltage to do that? Is this effective at all, compared to, say, a dual full bridge rectifier generating a positive and a negative supply from AC?

Comment: Have you read the datasheet?  The detailed description explains it.  e.g. https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/dst/icl7660-datasheet

Comment: After you read the linked datasheet description of operation, you can post a new question about anything specific that you don't understand.

Comment: It's called a charge pump - yes it steps up the voltage. See also voltage doubler, cockroft-walton multiplier for other uses of the same basic idea.

Comment: @JohnD "you can post a new question about anything specific that you don't understand" Don't want to open another question for this. But what would you think about how effective is AC-DC supply -> 7660 -> neg rail compared to AC-AC supply -> dual rectifier -> dual rail?

Comment: @user6329530 It depends on how much current you need from the negative rail.  If the charge pump is sufficient, then doing a tapped secondary or dual rectifier is probably wasteful.  If you need or might need more current than the charge pump can supply then a dual rail setup or an inverting buck-boost DC-DC would be under consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datasheet give a nice description about how this works but the diagram here from that datasheet shows it schematically:

[image]

Basically C1 charges up to Vin when the input waveform is HIGH and then it's basically reversed in polarity and connected to C2 which then gets charged at -Vin.

Comment: and this mechanism allows us to use the same chip for making a crude voltage doubler.

Comment: Hello, do you have information about how effective it is using this chip compared to generate dual rail from AC-AC supply (via dual rectifier where one rectifies the positive part of the AC and the other the negative thus creating two rails)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a charge pump CMOS voltage doubler for V+ and V- with an approximate 50 Ohm driver impedance. It uses the CMOS FETs as a low V diode to clamp the internal clock to charge each capacitor on each half cycle with the FET switches.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. If you have a choice what would you chose for effectivity, using a AC-DC supply and this chip to create negative rail or create the negative rail from an AC-AC supply where the negative part of the AC is rectified to a the negative DC rail?

Comment: It Depends: budget, load regulation error and ripple specs